# Attaching an usage plan to an API Key is not working with `createUsagePlanKey`

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to create an API key and attach it to an existing usage plan in API Gateway.

The creation is working but somehow I cannot attach the usage plan. Any idea what is going wrong?

I use the following code:

```
const params = {
  description: `token for ${email}`,
  enabled: true,
  name: email,
};

const { value: token, id: keyId } = await restApi
  .createApiKey(params)
  .promise();


const usagePlanParams: CreateUsagePlanKeyRequest = {
  keyId: keyId!,
  keyType: "API_KEY",
  usagePlanId: PLAN_ID,
};

const createUsagePlanKeyResult = await restApi.createUsagePlanKey(
  usagePlanParams
);
```

`keyId` and `PLAN_ID` are correct.

The usage plan is not attached to the API key (or vice-versa).

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Forgot adding `.promise()`

Sorry! :D